# Which settings do I need to tune GPU speed to train Neural Networks?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I'm working with Nvidia graphics cards and want to make sure I'm taking full advantage of their performance (in a safe way, no overclocking). Which settings do I need to perform in order to fully utilize their capabilities?

The only setting I used so far for faster startup is:

```
nvidia-smi -pm 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust how much of your GPU you want to sacrifice.

`config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4
session = tf.Session(config=config, ...)`

For example in this example from the official documentation, your program will use 40% of the total memory of your GPU.

For more details you can check out the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/using_gpu)